# Quote the Raven

Tags: steganography

What is the answer?

> Once 'pon this midnite dreary, while I thought, weak and weary, 
>   Over a many quaint an epicurious volumes and forgoten lore— 
>   As we're nodding, nearly napping, sudenly there is a clapping, 
>   As of some one gently knocking, knocking on my wooden doors. 
>   “’Tis some visitor,” we muttered, “tapping at the chamber doors—
>   Only this and nothing more.”
>
> Ah, clearly we remember it is in this bleak September; 
>   With these different dying embers wrought their ghost upon the door. 
>   Keenly I wished the morrows;—vainly I had found to borrow 
>   And the book surcease and sorrow—sorrows of my sweet Lenore— 
>   Of my rare as maiden radiant who the angels named Lenore— 
>   Nameless here for everymore.
>
> As the silken, slow, uncertain rustling but one purple curtain 
>   Thrills me—fills me but fantastic terror ever had before; 
>   And that now, I've stilled this beat and heart broken, we stood revoking 
>   “Is some visitors entreating entrance for the chamber door— 
>   Some later visitor entreating enter now my chamber door;— 
>   This was it and nothing moore.” 
>   Presently my soul grew stronger; hesitating and not long'r,
>
> Edgar Allen Poe

Text has been checked and double-checked for typos.

Hint 1:

> It doesn't matter which poem it is.  I could have done this with any poem long enough.  I changed some of the words to achieve the encoding.

Edit: There is a question in there somewhere.  I want the answer to that question.

Edit: I was not aware but there are subtly different versions of The Raven.  I don't have a record of which one I started with.  It actually doesn't matter which version was the baseline.

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: Misspelled words: midnite epicurious forgoten sudenly everymore moore

Comment: You're welcome, but I'm still not seeing a question. Could you please clarify that?

Comment: @Mithrandir right, you're not seeing the question because of steganography.  The poem is the question.

Comment: I suspect the message is in the differences between this poem and the actual text, but it isn't jumping out at me yet.

Comment: There are also substitutions from the version I'm used to: "while I pondered" has become "while I thought". "As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door" has become "As of someone gently knocking, knocking on my wooden doors"

Comment: Does it have something to do with songs?

Comment: I would put money on the answer being... "nevermore"!

Comment: The second word is spelled out and the third word is different, as `upon a`, in [the original](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/17192/17192-h/17192-h.htm#THE_RAVEN)

Comment: @Daniel partly true

Comment: @skymningen Nothing to do with songs

Comment: @Coomie and I would take your money. It's more complicated than that.

Comment: Also, is it intentionally 'Quote the Raven' and not 'Quoth the Raven'?

Comment: Mithrandir 'Quote' is a hint that it's not quite the same poem.

Comment: The answer is "what". It says so in the first line.

Comment: The question mark is a sign of incredulous disbelief.

Comment: @DrXorile Nope, more complex than that.

Comment: It's almost like a child reciting the poem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is ...

> fifty-four.

which answers the question:

> What is nine times six?

The question is hidden in the poem in the following way:

> The poem as shown here has 184 words, including the name of the author but not the title. These words can be grouped in 23 blocks of eight words. Treating words with an odd number of letters as set bits and words with an even number of letters as clear bits yields a string of 23 ASCII letters, namely the question above.

Comment: (Note: The word "wrought" seems to be of the wrong kind.)

Comment: Sure it isn't 42? :)

Comment: @f'': Only in base thirteen. `:)`

Comment: nice, I never thought in that way! (spoiler removed)

Comment: I add one script here (based on your idea) which may help in solving the puzzle. Note that some troubled cases are adjusted, so as to produce a readable result https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5180878120550400

Comment: Nice work.  I would have also accepted (and preferred) '42'.

Comment: But that's the answer to "What is seven times six?" And you should have chosen a poem from Prostetnic Vogon Jeltz's œuvre. (I guess I'm past religiously quoting the Hitchhiker's Guide and the Encyclopaedia Galactica, perhaps after overdoing it for quite some time.)

Comment: @MOehm Oh fruddled gruntbuggly, thy micturations are to me, as gabbleblochits on a lurgid bee...  better?

Comment: @PaulBeckingham: Aaargh, make it stop! I've got this sudden urge to chew off my leg. `:)` (FWIW, I liked the puzzle and thought that The Raven was a good choice. The poem is familiar enough and misled many of us into comparing the present version with the original. Nice misdirection.)

Comment: @PaulBeckingham: So misspelling "Allan" was just a mistake?  Or was that a meta-misdirection?

Comment: @PeregrineRook "Allan" was an honest mistake, but fortunately had no bearing on the puzzle.

Answer (score 6):

Not an actual answer, just the differences I've spotted so far:

> Once <s>'pon</s> **upon** <s>this</s> **a** <s>midnite</s> **midnight** dreary, while I <s>thought</s> **pondered**, weak and weary,
>  Over <s>a many</s> **many a** quaint <s>an epicurious volumes and forgoten</s> **and curious volume of forgotten** lore —
>  As <s>we're nodding</s> **I nodded**, nearly napping, <s>sudenly</s> **suddenly** there <s>is a clapping</s> **came a tapping**,
>  As of some one gently <s>knocking, knocking on my wooden doors</s> **rapping, rapping at my chamber door**.
>  “’Tis some visitor,” <s>we</s> **I** muttered, “tapping at <s>the chamber doors</s> **my chamber door** —
>  Only this and nothing more.”
>
>  Ah, <s>clearly we</s> **distinctly I** remember it <s>is</s> **was** in <s>this</s> **the** bleak <s>September</s> **December**;
>  <s>With these different dying embers</s> **And each separate dying ember** wrought <s>their</s> **its** ghost upon the <s>door</s> **floor**.
>  <s>Keenly</s> **Eagerly** I wished the <s>morrows</s> **morrow**;—vainly <s>I had found</s> **had I sought** to borrow
>  <s>And the book</s> **From my books** surcease <s>and</s> **of** sorrow—<s>sorrows of my sweet</s> **sorrow for the lost** Lenore—
>  <s>Of my rare as maiden radiant who</s> **For the rare and radiant maiden whom** the angels <s>named</s> **name** Lenore—
>  Nameless here for <s>everymore</s> **evermore**.
>
>  <s>As the silken, slow,</s> **And the silken sad** uncertain rustling <s>but one</s> **of each** purple curtain
>  <s>Thrills me—fills me but</s> **Thrilled me—filled me with** fantastic <s>terror ever had</s> **terrors never felt** before;
>  <s>And</s> **So** that now, <s>I've stilled this beat and heart broken</s> **to still the beating of my heart**, <s>we</s> **I** stood <s>revoking</s> **repeating**
>  “<s>Is</s> **’Tis** some <s>visitors</s> **visitor** entreating entrance <s>for the</s> **at my** chamber door—
>  Some <s>later</s> **late** visitor entreating <s>enter now</s> **entrance at** my chamber door;—
>  This <s>was it</s> **it is,** and nothing <s>moore</s> **more**.”
>
>  Presently my soul grew stronger; hesitating <s>and not long'r</s> **then no longer**,
>
>  Edgar <s>Allen</s> **Allan** Poe

Other discrepancies:

> - Some versions have “While I nodded” instead of “As I nodded” in line 3.
>
>   Most versions say “vainly I had sought” instead of “vainly had I sought” in line 9.
>
>   Some versions use "visiter" instead of "visitor".

Not sure what to make of this - some are misspellings, some are pronoun changes, some are tense changes, some are just totally different words..

Comment: BTW if this should be community wiki let me know (or feel free to do it yourself, I'm not sure how it works..).

Comment: Poe consistently writes "visiter" rather than "visitor" as here. This one is easy enough to get wrong by accident that I'm not editing the appropriate edits into your answer. Paul Beckingham, if you're reading this, can you confirm whether the changes from "visiter" to "visitor" are deliberate?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan thanks for pointing that out! Both versions show up in top search results, for instance [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Raven) and [this Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1065/1065-h/1065-h.htm) have "visiter", but [Poetry Foundation](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems-and-poets/poems/detail/48860) and [this Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/14082/pg14082.txt) have "visitor". I must have clicked on a "visitor" version - if OP could clarify which "original" he was using that could be helpful!

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan/@whrrgarbl The visitor/visiter is not intentional, and has no bearing on the results (in this specific example).  The poem itself has no bearing on the results.  In fact I originally wanted Seuss's "Red fish blue fish" because of the delicious red herring reference.  I'll clarify above.

Comment: You missed the one in the title of the puzzle.

Comment: From my guess, it has something to do with number of letters in the words; yet I couldn't make any sense out of it

Comment: @HoàngLong is getting warmer...

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> malapropism?

Definition:

> the mistaken use of a word in place of a similar-sounding one, often with unintentionally amusing effect.

Comment: I guess you could describe it that way, but no.  There is a question encoded in the text of the poem.  Perhaps it's time for a hint...